# Bounded (Db)Contexts in Entity Framework Architecture

Tags: .net, entity-framework, architecture, domain-driven-design

I have just watched Julie Lermans videos about using bounded contexts in EF (http://www.pluralsight.com/training/Courses/TableOfContents/efarchitecture) and I am now trying to work out the best way of implementing it (using POCOs). The two options I see are to either have one edmx model that defines everything and then handcraft the DbContexts to include the appropriate entities, or to have separate edmx models for each context and use the automatically created DbContexts.

Has anyone any ideas of which is best or any pros/cons of either?

IMHO: 
For a single model it is a lot less classes and a lot more code re-use (though these classes are created automatically so really it will only be the extra functionality that will manually be duplicated), but I will have a lot of classes in one place and for classes that need to be specialised these will each have to have different names. E.g. Customer, CustomerForFunctionalityX, CustomerForFunctionalityB.

With the separate models I can be much more stringent on what goes into a context as removing a property doesn't need to be a completely new entity, and I can name everything as I wish (i.e. all models can use a Customer object even if it differs between models), but now each context has entirely different entities even if they are all just mapping to the same table - which can also make it more difficult to pass them between contexts (this however shouldn't be needed too often otherwise it means the contexts have been defined wrong).

Comment: Why not use the unit of work pattern to create units of work that expose only the entities that a given team will work with?  If all teams are working against the same database, there really should be only one core team that is managing the database.  Bounded contexts seem to address with code a problem that is best addressed with team structure, IMO.

Comment: Certainly adding the UOW pattern could help and I like the UOW pattern, although it can add complexity. The main reason I like the separate edmxs is that one large edmx can become un-managable and also creating bounded edmxs makes sure the database developers can see exactly which entities belong to a context, rather than having to create customised entities for all UOWs in one model - it would be nice to have this separation throughout the whole model including the database model.

Answer (score 1):

I too am trying out bounded contexts, and have come across a (small?) problem with schemas. I created two contexts initially, one for domain data and one for audit type data (both entity change audit info and process info).
Initially, I found that the database only created tables from one context and ignored the other. I assumed that deriving the two contexts from a base context,

```
    public class BaseContext<TContext> : DbContext where TContext : DbContext
```

would generate the full database, but did not seem to do so.

One way around this was to create a "master" context which references all entities, but not expose it to the model. This worked ok, but now there is a small problem with db the schemas.

As our support people use SSMS to debug the system, I thought it would be a good idea to change the schema along the same lines as the bounded context, so I specified the schema in the master context (OnModelCreating() override method withing the master context):

```
    modelBuilder.Entity<Address>()
            .HasKey(b => new {b.AddressId,b.EffectiveStartDate})
            .ToTable("Addresses", "Esr");
```

where "Esr" is the schema.
However, upon trying to write data with the bounded context, an error is occurring which indicates that the bounded context is using "dbo" schema. I'm sure there's a way around this. I do have a nagging feeling that this may not be worth all the effort.

Sure, bounded contexts give a cleaner feel to the application and I like the idea of structuring the code to fit the domain structure, as this puts the overall architecture closer to the specification and helps when thinking about tests.

On the other hand, are my fellow programmers going to have trouble picking the right entities when coding against a single monolithic context?

The separation of contexts is much more useful when applied in the area of support or UAT, and these people have to work with the application in terms of the overall business process.

Comment: Interestingly, this problem goes away when you switch from fluent configuration to data annotations. You have to switch ALL the configuration, as once EF sees data annotations it seems to ignore the fluent (which I left in place). I guess that it works because all the contexts are working from the same POCO classes, hence you can define a common db schema in the data annotation.

Comment: After some more experimentation, I tried making the logical split at the Repository level ("Bounded Repositories"?). As the repository sits between the dbcontext and the model, it feels like the right structure. The only problem is that some parts of the model work generically with both repositories, so to determine which one should be used I had to use type parameters liberally. The result works but is not the best looking code.

Answer (score 1):

We are discussing this exact problem now and I too have watched Julies videos as well as researched DDD.  I would like my data access to reflect the unit of work but we are running into a problem where a table name cannot be used in more than one EDMX.

Let's say I have tables Customer, CustomerOrder, Order, OrderInventory, Item.
On one screen I just want to display the customer information so my EDMX for that only has Customer.  Now another use case is I all invoices for a customer, in this use case I have Customer, CustomerOrder, Order, OrderInventory, and Item.  We get this exception:
The mapping of CLR type to EDM type is ambiguous because multiple CLR types match the EDM type 'Customer'. Previously found CLR type 'A.Customer', newly found CLR type 'B.Customer'.

How are you guys getting around this error message?  Are you renaming every table that is duplicated across all the EDMX files?

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you read up on what bounded contexts are and what problems they try to solve. From the Bounded Context [definition](http://domaindrivendesign.org/node/91):

> Explicitly define the context within which a model applies. Explicitly set boundaries in terms of team organization, usage within specific parts of the application, and physical manifestations such as code bases and database schemas. Keep the model strictly consistent within these bounds, but don’t be distracted or confused by issues outside.

Having a single EDMX model would violate that explicit boundary. You can probably imagine the friction that could occur when teams from different contexts work on the same EDMX model.
In your case however, you may feel that the cost of that explicit boundary and integration between contexts is too high. Using a [Shared Kernel](http://www.markhneedham.com/blog/2009/03/30/ddd-recognising-relationships-between-bounded-contexts/) would allow you to share your EDMX model between contexts.

Comment: Julie in her videos seems to use one edmx but that just didn't sit with me. I agree that a single edmx could cause friction (and also a massive model!), however as there is only one database I don't think that in this scenario we can completely be consistent with all the rules. Should I still try to follow this pattern even if I can't succeed with all the parts of it?

Answer (score 0):

> but now each context has entirely different entities even if they are
>   all just mapping to the same table

This is a sign that you may not actually need multiple bounded contexts (BC). The primary goal of a BC is [functional cohesion](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cohesion_%28computer_science%29) and if your model ends up having a great deal of chatter between BCs (in other words coupling) then it is likely an indication that a single BC would be more appropriate. Before isolating different BCs, consider if your model would be better served by partitioning into modules (namespaces in .NET). Take a look at [Implementing Domain-Driven Design](http://my.safaribooksonline.com/book/project-management/9780133039900/chapter-9dot-modules/ch09) for more on this.

Also, often times, a variety of query requirements can make it seem like multiple BCs are at play where in reality you just need different ways of viewing the same entity. This is very different from having completely different entities all together. Consider using the [read-model pattern](http://gorodinski.com/blog/2012/04/25/read-models-as-a-tactical-pattern-in-domain-driven-design-ddd/) to solve this.

Comment: Isolating functionality areas is what I am primarily using bounded contexts for, however I think it unlikely that you would be able to do this without some entity overlap. I would certainly not want to allow much coupling between contexts as that would more mean I have split the areas up incorrectly rather than a problem with the pattern.

Comment: In my scenario the system is going to consist of several products all sharing a single database. There will be some shared and some product-specific functionality so I am trying to work out the best way of splitting this. The idea of clearly defined bounded contexts seems like a nice way of separating the functionality and then use namespaces to provide the product scope (product-specific or common) of that functionality. Does that sound like a good idea? A lot of the entities will be readonly and therefore using the bounded context allows this to be done cleanly.

Comment: If you partition the domain into multiple BCs, you should also partition the database around those BCs, otherwise your boundaries may leak. Ask yourself whether you have a shared entity or whether you have different perspectives of the entity. BCs can certainly share entity _identity_, in which case one BC may "attach" functionality to an entity from another BC. Can you provide more details about your domain?

Comment: I think I am looking at different views of the same entity because I want to be able to lock-down an entity to prevent unnecessary data being brought along. We will be using WCF so reducing data is very important, as well as simplifying the models for developers. Therefore, for example, I would like to have a module that deals with Customers in its entirety and then other modules that can simply view specific data relevent to the functionality only.

Comment: The project is still in the initial requirements gathering phase but it is replacing an existing one so I will try and explain the overall domain. The application will consist of many products (finance, property etc) which will all share data (such as business details, customers, suppliers etc) but will also have its own data that other programs may be able to see but likely won't be able to be modified. We will be using MVVM & PRISM so functionality will be modular which would map quite well to bounded contexts.

Comment: I don't really want to split the database up as I think EF will do enough to hide that complexity so just creating bounded contexts at the EF context level should give us enough separation but without the likelihood of leaking. I am happy to read other peoples views on all of this though.